# Should each task/process/role run as its own user on a Windows server?

Tags: windows, security, best-practices

I know that on Linux servers, it's widely considered best practice to run each task/role/process/server/program as its own user and usually in its own group.

How should separate tasks be handled on a Windows server, especially when they don't run as a service?

Comment: Good question. I'm looking forward to the answers/comments.